# Moderated regression with categorical predictors

Tags: regression, interaction

I would like to do a moderated regression with SPSS. My problem is that the independent variable (predictor) is categorical, wheras the moderator as well as the dependent variable are interval variables.
I already generated 2 dummy variables out of the categorical predictor variable (it has 3 categories). What exactly are the next steps I have to take?
I hope you can help me.
Thank you very much!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use a software tool.

Comment: Are you asking how to fit a model with an interaction? Are you asking how to use SPSS? Please clarify.